# How do I create an intermediary table between 3+ tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm building a relatively simple database which has 4 entities:

- **Modules**, stored in *modules* table, each with a unique id, which (in the real world) are comprised of any number of...
- **Questions**, stored in the *questions* table
- **Exams**, stored in the *exams* table
- and **Slides**, stored in the *slides* table

The *questions, exams and slides* tables all have different schemas, aside from a unique id field for each record in each table.

I now want to use an intermediate table, *moduleParts*, to:

- store all of the 'parts' (exams, questions & slides) that make up a module.
- store the order of parts within a module

Additionally, a module may contain the same 'part' more than once, and a part may be assigned to multiple modules.

Each record in this table will have its own ID, the ID of the module the 'part' belongs to and... well, I don't know what to use to store the reference to the question / exam / slide.

1. We can't use the item's own ID from its own table, as this wouldn't be unique within the *moduleParts* table (exam 4 / module 2 clashing with slide 4 / module 2)
2. Storing the appropriate table name alongside seems clumsy
3. Creating a new table, *modulePartsTypes*, which is a list of module part types and their respective table names - as clumsy and more convoluted than number 2.

It's been a while since I've had to plan out a DB so... is there an obvious / best-practice solution I'm missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "parts? "   Do these include lessons, exams and slides?

Comment: Exactly that. Will update.

Comment: okay, check answer below for a couple of options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach 1:

The way that I would do this is to create link tables with each of the "parts"

That way you can have **ModulesLessons**, **ModulesExams**, and **ModulesSlides** as three distinct tables.

Each table would then have two primary keys, each of which are foreign keys to their respective tables.

For instance, **ModulesLessons** would have `ModuleID` and `LessonID`.  Both of these keys would be primary keys (and therefore unique), and `ModuleID` would be a foreign key to the id on **Modules** and `LessonID` would be use a foreign key from **Lesson**.

With this approach you wouldn't have problems with the conflicts you describe above.   It does, however assume that a Module would only have a Lesson once per module, and similarly for Exams and Slides.  It will require three tables but once built you will be able to have the many-to-many flexibility you need.

### Approach 2

You could make one table with more primary keys, such as you describe, called **ModulesParts** and create primary keys for `ModuleID`, `LessonID`,`ExamId`, and `SlideID`

This should work but analysis of what is going on could be more confusing.  However one of the advantages of this approach is it would be pretty easy to create another key, which would have something like `ModuleOrder` so you could easily organize the elements within your module to appear in the order that you want them to appear.

Here's a demo.  Note you could use a 0 to indicate items that should not be shown (as in the last row).  In fact it would probably make sense to have these default to 0, unless you want two items to appear together.

```
ModuleID    LessonID    ExamId  SlideID  Module Order
    1           1           1       1       1
    1           1           1       2       4
    1           1           2       1       2
    1           2           1       1       3
    2           1           1       1       1
    2           1           2       2       2
    2           2           1       1       3
    2           0           0       2       4
```

### Approach 3

If you need to use parts like lessons or exams more than once within a module, there's another way of doing this.

Create 2 primary keys, one of them is ModuleID as before (foreign key to Modules) and ModuleOrder, which only lives on this table.  As items can only appear in order on this table, there will only be one numerical order per Module.   The other items, such as LessonID, ExamID, and SlideID can exist as non-unique indexes, so you can have the option of having, for example, the same exam appear twice in the same module.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A Module may have N Lessons / Slides / Exams, and I forgot to mention but need to have a mechanism to 'order' these disparate elements within a module (the original purpose of ModuleParts table)

Comment: See Approach 2 then.  That should definitely work for you.  Assuming that a particular lesson/slide/exam would not appear twice.  But you can definitely have  N Lessons / Slides / Exams.

Comment: Approach 2 is quite nice - but I can't be 100% certain again that a module won't contain the same question / exam etc just once.

Comment: Hmmm, that's an odd situation.  A module can include any 4 part combo only once, however, if it's not going to ever appear at the same point in the module (which would be impossible in fact), you could also make `ModuleOrder` a primary key as well (it just wouldn't be a foreign key)  you could have a duplicate of, for example, an exam, but it would appear at a different order in the specific module.  Then you are working with 5 keys.   That should definitely work :)

Comment: Actually, I have an even better idea, which is a bit cleaner.  You could just have two primary keys, ModuleID and ModuleOrder, and the rest of the keys could just be foreign keys, and you could use them as many times you like.   I'll make the edit above to include an Approach 3

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear whether a given lesson, slide, or exam can be part of multiple modules or not. If not then simply add a "module_id" to each of those 3 tables and then join them in your query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM modules
JOIN lessons ON lessons.module_id = modules.id
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM modules
JOIN slides ON slides.module_id = modules.id
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM modules
JOIN exams ON exams.module_id = modules.id
ORDER BY modules.id, ...
```

Or, perhaps easier, do 3 different queries for each of the different parts since you will probably have different enough columns in each table that the UNION will be awkward.

Comment: I quite like this, but I can't 100% rule out a 'part' being part of

Comment: more than 1 module (blargh phone keyboard)

Comment: Updated the question to say as much, but there's also the need to store an order for the 'parts' within 1 module, as well as a slide / question / exam being part of more than 1 module.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the purpose of including "slides" (I guess you mean presentations) as module parts. I think they are rather lesson parts. Thyt's why I omitted them in the following discussion.

It's always good to start with an information design model in the form of a UML class diagram:

[image]

From such an information design model, we can derive various data models, including an SQL database model, which could be described in the following way:

```
modules( 
  id  PK, 
  name
)
lessons( 
  module_id FK(modules), 
  sequence_no, 
  title
  PK( module_id, sequence_no)
)
exams( 
  module_id FK(modules), 
  sequence_no, 
  description
  PK( module_id, sequence_no)
)
```

PK stands for PRIMARY KEY, and FK for FOREIGN KEY.

Notice that the component tables `lessons` and `exams` have a reference (foreign key) attribute to the composite table `modules`, which is also part of their primary key composed of `module_id` and `sequence_no`. In this  approach, the attribute `sequence_no` is used with a twofold role: it's both a relative identifier (by being part of the PK) and it encodes the order of the components (lessons and exams). This is a simplified approach, which is only okay, if there are no other tables referencing these component tables. Otherwise, another relative identifier attribute has to be added (such as `lesson name` and `exam date`) for replacing `sequence_no` in the PK.

Comment: I made a mistake in my original question - it's a 'question' and not a 'lesson' - now updated. I'm not sure what the sequenceNo here is - for storing the order of parts within a module?

Comment: Using sequence numbers for components (like exams) is a common technique for both identifying them relative to their composite (their module) and defining an order for them.

Comment: Thanks @gwag - do you have any references / sources I can see to read up on the approach?

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't have a reference. I'll add an explanation to my answer.